# gin HTMLGlob not applying **

Tags: go, templates, go-gin

I have a gin v1.8.1 go program that uses templates.  Main go file is `cmd/app/app.go`.  Inside it, I have this

```golang
    r := gin.Default()

    cwd, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("CWD is %s", cwd)
    r.LoadHTMLGlob("../../templates/**/*")
```

When I run I get this panic

```
CWD is /Users/paul/src/personal/app/cmd/app
panic: html/template: pattern matches no files: `../../templates/**/*`

goroutine 1 [running]:
html/template.Must(0x0, {0x4aac5a0, 0xc000584490})
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.18.3/libexec/src/html/template/template.go:374 +0x8b
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*Engine).LoadHTMLGlob(0xc0005b04e0, {0x4a2e2ae, 0x14})
    /Users/paul/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/gin.go:251 +0x15e
main.main()
    /Users/paul/src/personal/app/cmd/app/app.go:31 +0x169
```

When I remove the double star (`r.LoadHTMLGlob("../../templates/*")`), it works fine.  I know the standard library globber does not handle double star, but [gin docs](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#html-rendering) says theirs does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I have just misunderstood how this implementation of globbing works.  I added a new template, `test/index.html` and tried the syntax `../../templates/**/*`.  Gin running in debug mode lists all of the templates it finds.  Rather than listing the templates in the base directory, it only finds `index.html`. The `**` means match a directory *that must exist*.